# Value error with tensorflow while loading csv with iris example

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, artificial-intelligence

When trying to run a simple get data sequence on Jupyter, for a system to recognise the iris flower tyoes teough fisher's table,  the error:

```
  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-12-269564554b65> in <module>
 10 training_set = base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
 11                                      features_dtype=np.float32,
 ---> 12                                      target_dtype=np.float32)
 13 test_set = base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TEST,
 14                                  features_dtype=np.float32,

 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py in load_csv_with_header(filename, target_dtype, features_dtype, target_column)
 46     data_file = csv.reader(csv_file)
 47     header = next(data_file)
 ---> 48     n_samples = int(header[0])
 49     n_features = int(header[1])
 50     data = np.zeros((n_samples, n_features), dtype=features_dtype)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.1'
```

is being shown. The error indicates that it is unable to use the int() function despite the fact that there is no int in the code at all. Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets import base

# Data files
IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set = base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
                                     features_dtype=np.float32,
                                     target_dtype=np.float32)
test_set = base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TEST,
                                 features_dtype=np.float32,
                                 target_dtype=np.float32)

print(training_set.data)

print(training_set.target)
```

Why is `target_dytype=np.int` not working, as the error shows?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is contained in header[0] ? It gives the same error if I run `int('5.1')` so you need to convert the type before converting it to int

Comment: To be honest, I'm kind of a newbie, and actually dont know what header[0] is. Would it help if I showed a part of the .csv file?

Comment: The problem is header[0] is treated as string rather than float

Comment: `header[0]` is part of the `tensorflow.base` library and not OP's code. @codingPerson, does you data have headers?

Comment: can you try`target_dytype= np.int16 `or `target_dytype=np.int64`

Comment: @BernardL, no, it doesn't. Should it?

Comment: @mad_, still no result.

Comment: Updated my answer with different load methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right there, you are not able to convert a decimal to an integer. Try using the numpy data type `float32` instead.

```
target_dtype=np.float32
```

**Update**

`tensorflow.base` has several `load_csv..`, you can try either `base.load_csv_without_header` or `base.load_csv`.

The specific `iris` tensorflow example is applied on to their own data set, [here](http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_test.csv) where the first column header stores the number of examples, which caused the error below:

```
 46     data_file = csv.reader(csv_file)
 47     header = next(data_file)
 ---> 48     n_samples = int(header[0])
 49     n_features = int(header[1])
```

`header` returns you the first line of the csv file, and `n_samples` is used to store the number of samples from the first column.

Comment: I've tried it to no avail; the error is the same, despite re-running the code as you told in the answer

Comment: Yes, the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.1'` is being shown

Comment: Did you change for both your train and test? And can you post your full error traceback?

Comment: And if I were to add a header, and keep the with_header, why is the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Sepal legnth'` there now?

Comment: Ok, got it, I believe the tensorflow example was specifically for their dataset where the first column header stores the number of samples. That is why it does not work for your datasets. You can refer to the example from tf [here](http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv)

Comment: @BernardL is correct. The dataset has int values(Number of samples) in the header.